# Change default position of product in categories from 1 to product ID in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, sorting, position, magento-1.7, categories

In Magento 1.7.0.2, I am adding a lot of products from the backend but the positions of these new items in their corresponding categories are 0 or 1. So when sorting on the frontend, I get arbitrary sorting by postion.

I set the position of these items in their categories to be equal to the product_id directly on the database (table catalog_category_product), and sorting works correctly. So the solution is to set the position of the product in a category to be equal to the product_id in the code, but I don't know where and how to do that.

Any help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the function _saveCategories in the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product this appears to do what you are looking for. Have a look around for the call to insertMultiple. This will take in a $data array containing category_id, product_id and position (which oddly is always set to 1)

I would think that at this point you can make your edit. Though I would suggest that you rewrite the class rather than editing the core code.